# Command (Batch) File - use of quotes around directory names

Tags: directory, batch-file, quotes

I found the technique below in another StackOverflow issue.  It gets the proper "Program Files" directory name, whether the file runs on 32 or 64-bit version of Windows.

How can I get around the problem below.  If I don't put double quotes around %programfiles% I get an error on the set.

```
set BTDFProgFiles=%programfiles(x86)%
if %BTDFProgFiles%=="" set BTDFProgFiles=%programfiles%
echo BTDFProgFiles=%BTDFProgFiles%
%BTDFMSBuildPath% "%BTDFProgFiles%\FRB.EC.Common\%2\Deployment\FRB.EC.Common.BizTalk.Deployment.btdfproj"  etc...
```

If I put double quotes there, the SET statements work, but then the parm to the build program shows with two parms:

```
set BTDFProgFiles="%programfiles(x86)%"
if %BTDFProgFiles%=="" set BTDFProgFiles="%programfiles%"
echo BTDFProgFiles=%BTDFProgFiles%
%BTDFMSBuildPath% "%BTDFProgFiles%\FRB.EC.Common\%2\Deployment\FRB.EC.Common.BizTalk.Deployment.btdfproj"  etc...
```

Interpreted as: 
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBu
ild.exe" "C:\Program Files"\FRB.EC.BookTransfer\1.1\Deployment\FRB.EC.BookTransf
er.BizTalk.Deployment.btdfproj"  etc...

MSBuild thinks that I'm trying to pass more than one project.; 
MSBUILD: Error MSB1008: Only one projet can be specified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use quotes, but in a slightly other way.

`set var="my quoted string"` sets **var** to `"my quoted string"`
`set "var=my quoted string"` sets **var** to `my quoted string`
The second method can quotes string without adding the quotes.

And to echo strings in a secure way without quotes you could use the delayed expansion.

So your code should be changed to

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "BTDFProgFiles=%programfiles(x86)%"
if "%BTDFProgFiles%"=="" set "BTDFProgFiles=%programfiles%"
echo BTDFProgFiles=!BTDFProgFiles!
"%BTDFMSBuildPath%" "%BTDFProgFiles%\FRB.EC.Common\%2\Deployment\FRB.EC.Common.BizTalk.Deployment.btdfproj"
```